# I am trying to upgrade MySQL connector from version 5 to version 8, but I am getting the following error. Is MySQL 8 not supported by hibernate 3?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, grails, groovy

I have a grails(version - 2.5.1) project which uses Hibernate(version - 3.6.10.19)

I am getting the following type of error in my application when trying to upgrade MySQL connector from version 5 to version 8 -

```
Message: Hibernate operation: could not execute query; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select this_.id as id545_0_, this_.version as version545_0_, this_.customer_host_name as customer3_545_0_, this_.customer_name as customer4_545_0_, this_.id as 5_545_0_, this_.shard as shard545_0_ from customer this_ where this_.customer_host_name=?]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The type registry TypeRegistry(id=764316860,loader=org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader) does not know about type id 10136; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The type registry TypeRegistry(id=764316860,loader=org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader) does not know about type id 10136
```

My BuildConfig.groovy file has following lines declared -

```
dependencies {
      runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.19'
}

plugins {
      runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.19'
}
```

And my external datasource file hsa following type of content -

```
dataSource {
    shard = false
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    dbCreate = "update" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&relaxAutoCommit=true&useSSL=false"
    username="test"
    password="test"
properties {
       initialSize=5
       maxActive=50
       minIdle=5
       maxIdle=25
       maxWait = 10000
       maxAge = 10 * 60000
       timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000
       minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000
       validationQuery="SELECT 1"
       validationInterval=15000
       testWhileIdle=true
       testOnBorrow=true
       testOnReturn=false
       jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
       defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
   }
}
```

What might have caused the issue or MySQL 8 is not supported by Hibernate 3 ?

Comment: Which dialect are you using?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I tried to use "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect", but it did not work

Comment: "I tried to use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect, but it did not work" -  Does `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` exist in Hibernate 3?

Comment: Is it the case that the error mentioned in the question came out of an app that is using version 3.6.10.19 of the hibernate plugin and in that app `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` was used to generated the problematic SQL?