# How to configure Grails 2.5.1 to use Hibernate 5?

Tags: hibernate, maven, grails, groovy, mysql-connector

I have a Grails 2.5.1 project which currently uses Hibernate 3.6.10.19 and I want to upgrade my hibernate to version 5 in order to support MySQL 8 connector (Right now I am using MySQL 5 connector in my project). So is it possible to use Hibernate 5 in Grails 2 in order to support MySQL 8 connector or is there an alternative ?

Right now my BuildConfig.groovy file has dependencies as follows -

```
dependencies {
     runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.48'
 }

plugins {
        runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.19'
}
```

Comment: I think this is basically the same question as [I am trying to upgrade MySQL connector from version 5 to version 8, but I am getting the following error. Is MySQL 8 not supported by hibernate 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65790729/i-am-trying-to-upgrade-mysql-connector-from-version-5-to-version-8-but-i-am-get)

Answer (score 2):

For Hibernate 5 you look to need to use GORM 5 with Grails 3.  Below is a post from Graeme.

https://grails.io/post/133798408743/announcing-gorm-5-suite

GORM 5 comes with releases for Grails 2 (minus Hibernate 5 support), Grails 3.x and Spring Boot, as well as supporting standalone usage. This means whatever environment you choose to develop in GORM support is available.

http://gorm.grails.org/5.0.x/hibernate/manual/index.html